# Convergence of power series - Do we have to check also the endpoints?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

For whoch $x\in \mathbb{R}$ does the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}(x-2)^n$$ converge?

To check this we use the power series criterium, or not?

So we calculate first the radius $$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right |=\cdots =\frac{1}{4}$$ Then we have that the power series converges for $$|x-2|<R\Rightarrow |x-2|<\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \frac{7}{4}<x<\frac{9}{4}$$ Do we have to check also the endpoints, $x=\frac{7}{4}$ and $x=\frac{9}{4}$ ?

Comment: There's various examples.   In general convergence on the boundary circle is up in the air.

Comment: So we just say that we have convergence for $x$ in the interval $\left (\frac{7}{4}, \frac{9}{4}\right )$ ? So we don't have to consider the endpoints ? @Cpc

Comment: Unless you're instructed.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! :-) @Cpc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Consider $\sum (-1)^{n} \binom {2n} {n} 4^{-n}$. This is an alternating series. Let $a_n =\binom {2n} {n} 4^{-n}$. Then $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$ simplifies to $1-\frac 1 {2(n+1)}<1$. In particular, $a_{n+1} <a_n$. Also, $a_n \to 0$. By Alternating Series Test the series converges. So the original series converges when $x=\frac 7 4$. I will leave the other end point to you. [Use Stirling's formula to prove divergence in this case].

Comment: For $x=\frac{7}{4}$ we have the term $\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \left (-\frac{1}{4}\right )^n$ , right? This goes to $0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$, or not? The same holds also for $x=\frac{9}{4}$ where we get the term $\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \left (\frac{1}{4}\right )^n$. So how do we prove that these two diverge?